# How to group pandas data frame on the basis of index value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby

I need to group My Pandas data frame object `Source` on the basis of the first and second columns. The columns are not named. so 0, 1, 2, 3 ... is indicating while printing the data frame.
I tried,

```
grouped_Source = Source.groupby(0)
```

and also

```
grouped_Source = Source.groupby("0")
```

but it's not working.

Thank you!

Comment: what was the error/problem for "grouped_Source = Source.groupby(0)"?

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grouped_Source = Source.groupby(Source.columns[0:2].tolist())
```

`Source.columns[0:2]` will give you the first two columns' names.